# drop np array rows based on element uniqueness and one other condition

Tags: arrays, numpy

Consider the 2d integer array below:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 3, 5, 2, 8],
                [9, 6, 1, 7, 6],
                [4, 4, 1, 8, 0],
                [2, 3, 1, 8, 5],
                [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                [6, 6, 7, 9, 1],
                [5, 3, 1, 8, 2]])
```

**PROBLEM: Eliminate rows from arr that meet two conditions:

a) The row's elements MUST be unique

b) From these unique-element rows, I want to eliminate the permutation duplicates.**

All other rows in arr are kept.

In the example given above, the rows with `indices 0,3,4, and 6` meet condition a).  Their elements are unique.

Of these 4 rows, the ones with indices 0,3,6 are permutations of each other:  I want to keep
one of them, say index 0, and ELIMINATE the other two.

The output would look like:

```
[[1, 3, 5, 2, 8],
 [9, 6, 1, 7, 6],
 [4, 4, 1, 8, 0],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [6, 6, 7, 9, 1]])
```

I can identify the rows that meet condition a) with something like:

```
s = np.sort(arr,axis=1)
arr[~(s[:,:-1] == s[:,1:]).any(1)]
```

But, I'm not sure at all how to eliminate the permutation duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way -

```
# Sort along row
b = np.sort(arr,axis=1)

# Mask of rows with unique elements and select those rows
m = (b[:,:-1] != b[:,1:]).all(1)
d = b[m]

# Indices of uniq rows
idx = np.flatnonzero(m)

# Get indices of rows among them that are unique as per possible permutes
u,stidx,c = np.unique(d, axis=0, return_index=True, return_counts=True)

# Concatenate unique ones among these and non-masked ones
out = arr[np.sort(np.r_[idx[stidx], np.flatnonzero(~m)])]
```

Alternatively, final step could be optimized further, with something like this -

```
m[idx[stidx]] = 0
out = arr[~m]
```

Comment: Works well and quickly.   The comments and alternate solution were most helpful.